# problem comparing a bash array value, with a string defined in the script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I'm not really great at scripting but I've been fighting and trying every variation I can find on different threads.
I'm rewriting some old scripts I created for backup/restore of virtualhosts and attempting to use a single config file (blah.cfg) for the scripts, most use the same variables anyway..

settings.cfg

```
enabled=yes
password=thisisastring
```

script1.sh

```
comparepass=thisisastring
##############################################################
typeset -A config # init array
config=()
while read line
do
    if echo $line | grep -F = &>/dev/null
    then
        varname=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 1)
        config[$varname]=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
    fi
done < settings.cfg
clear
echo 1: $comparepass
echo 2: ${config[password]}
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------
if [ $comparepass == "${config[password]}" ]; then
    echo matches:  $comparepass vs ${config[password]}
else
    echo does not match:  $comparepass vs ${config[password]}
fi
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------
exit
#############################################################################
```

Nothing I try matches comparepass (set in the script) and password (set in the cfg file), but if I echo them to output, they are the same..

```
1: thisisastring
2: thisisastring
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
does not match: thisisastring vs thisisastring
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried different variations depending on what thread I've read:

```
if [ "$comparepass" == ${config[password]} ];
if [ $comparepass == "${config[password]}" ];
if [ "$comparepass" == "${config[password]}" ];
if [[ $comparepass == ${config[password]} ]];    #this is a binary check?
```

I also tried tried assigning the array into a regular variable

```
compareagainst=${config[password]}
    if [ $comparepass == $compareagainst ]; then
        echo matches:  $comparepass vs $compareagainst
    else
        echo does not match:  $comparepass vs $compareagainst
    fi
```

with the same result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
does not match: thisisastring vs thisisastring
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm confused.. out of the code world for so long I just don't remember anymore..

dev@sandbox:~/backup-tools$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: I might just have an idea. Can you show the output of `sed -n l settings.cfg`  ?

Comment: oh yea!  i didn't think about that..    /r's everywhere it appears.  Actually.. stuff all over the place.
sed -n l settings.cnf

enabled=yes\r$
password=thisisastring\r$

#####################################################################\
##\r$
#\r$
# base location where your virtual hosts reside\r$
# example 1:  you have only one host on your server and the Directory\
 structure is:\r$
#\r$
# \342\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\200 var\r$
#    \342\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\200 www\r$
#\t\t\342\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\200 html\r$

Comment: Great, so we are making progress. I've also refactored your script a bit to make it less complex. See answer:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `settings.cfg` file doesn't contain carriage return characters at the end (which is usually the case)

To fix the `settings.cfg` file run

```
dos2unix settings.cfg
```

script refactored:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

comparepass=thisisastring
##############################################################
while IFS== read -r _ value || [[ -n $line ]]
do
  val="$value" 
done < settings.cfg
printf 'pass from config:\t%s\n'  "$val"
printf 'pass from script:\t%s\n'  "$comparepass"
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------
if [[ $val == $comparepass ]]; then
    printf '%s and %s match\n' "$val" "$comparepass"
else
    printf '%s and %s do not match\n' "$val" "$comparepass"
fi
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------
exit
```

Also I'd advise not to put an extension to your script. Just name it `script`

Here is the piece where you store the init formatted `settings.cfg` file into an "associative" array in bash

```
# Declare the associative array
declare -A settings

while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
    # Strip leading/trailing whitespace from the key and value in case there are any
    key="${key// /}"
    value="${value// /}"
    settings[$key]="$value"
done < settings.cfg

# Loop through the keys and print the values of the array
for key in "${!settings[@]}"; do
    echo "$key = ${settings[$key]}"
done
```

Comment: excellent, thank you for the help.. I used sed -i -e 's/\r$//' settings.cfg and it appears to have worked as well.. I will read on the differences between dos2unix .
For the refactoring, it doesn't appear to be creating an array?  I will be using 20 other variables from the cfg across a few different scripts.

Comment: can you explain why not use .sh on the end?   sorry for the rudimentary questions.. i thought extensionless indicated a binary file, not a script?

Comment: There are a few reasons why not to use .sh extension. One being convention. See https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html  . Furthermore, .sh extension might confuse users and in some cases it breaks bash functionality if the script is written in bash. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FullBashGuide which explains not to use `.sh` extension

Comment: Ok, in that case, see my update